# Errors from javascript verifying simplemodal form

Tags: php, javascript, forms, contacts, simplemodal

I'm editing the Simplemodal contact form on my html website to create a form. All the editing was going fine until I ran into the issue that the javascript results in getting an undefined value. I am trying to add a few fields and take away the message and the checkbox field. The first chunk is the original code and I added the second chunk:

```
            if (!$('#contact-container #contact-name').val()) {
            contact.message += 'First Name is required. ';
            fail = true;
        }

        if (!$('#contact-container #contact-lname').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Last Name is required. ';
            fail = true;
        }
```

The first if statement works fine, but the second statement has an undefined value when processing the js. The actual form shows up fine, yet this processing doesn't work. The following code is what I have in the file:

```
            <label for='contact-name'>First Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' />
        <label for='contact-lname'>Last Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-lname' class='contact-input' name='lname' tabindex='1002' />
```

The original is intact, I just added the last two lines. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ The code I'm having issues with is the contact.js where I have an issue with my modified lines above.

EDIT: This is the code which activates the Simplemodal via the webpage

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='content'>
    <div id='contact-form'>
        <h3><a href='#' class='contact'>Support the Cause!</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The modified contact.js is below and uses jquery and jquerySimplemodal (which both don't effect the way the processing of the code is done). The other two js files are via the link above.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var contact = {
    message: null,
    init: function () {
        $('#contact-form input.contact, #contact-form a.contact').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // load the contact form using ajax
            $.get("data/contact.php", function(data){
                // create a modal dialog with the data
                $(data).modal({
                    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                    position: ["15%",],
                    overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                    containerId: 'contact-container',
                    onOpen: contact.open,
                    onShow: contact.show,
                    onClose: contact.close
                });
            });
        });
    },
    open: function (dialog) {
        // add padding to the buttons in firefox/mozilla
        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            $('#contact-container .contact-button').css({
                'padding-bottom': '2px'
            });
        }
        // input field font size
        if ($.browser.safari) {
            $('#contact-container .contact-input').css({
                'font-size': '.9em'
            });
        }

        // dynamically determine height
        var h = 280;
        if ($('#contact-subject').length) {
            h += 26;
        }
        if ($('#contact-cc').length) {
            h += 22;
        }

        var title = $('#contact-container .contact-title').html();
        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Loading...');
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn(200, function () {
            dialog.container.fadeIn(200, function () {
                dialog.data.fadeIn(200, function () {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                        height: h
                    }, function () {
                        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html(title);
                        $('#contact-container form').fadeIn(200, function () {
                            $('#contact-container #contact-name').focus();

                //          $('#contact-container .contact-cc').click(function () {
                //              var cc = $('#contact-container #contact-cc');
                    //          cc.is(':checked') ? cc.attr('checked', '') : cc.attr('checked', 'checked');
                    //      })
                    ;

                            // fix png's for IE 6
                            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
                                $('#contact-container .contact-button').each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).css('backgroundImage').match(/^url[("']+(.*\.png)[)"']+$/i)) {
                                        var src = RegExp.$1;
                                        $(this).css({
                                            backgroundImage: 'none',
                                            filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="' +  src + '", sizingMethod="crop")'
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
    show: function (dialog) {
        $('#contact-container .contact-send').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // validate form
            if (contact.validate()) {
                var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message');
                msg.fadeOut(function () {
                    msg.removeClass('contact-error').empty();
                });
                $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Sending...');
                $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);
                $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                    height: '80px'}, 
                function () {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeIn(200, function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'data/contact.php',
                            data: $('#contact-container form').serialize() + '&action=send',
                            type: 'post',
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeOut(200, function () {
                                    $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Thank you!');
                                    msg.html(data).fadeIn(200);
                                });
                            },
                            error: contact.error
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                if ($('#contact-container .contact-message:visible').length > 0) {
                    var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message div');
                    msg.fadeOut(200, function () {
                        msg.empty();
                        contact.showError();
                        msg.fadeIn(200);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-message').animate({
                        height: '30px'
                    }, contact.showError);
                }

            }
        });
    },
    close: function (dialog) {
        $('#contact-container .contact-message').fadeOut();
        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('');    <!--here-->
        $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);
        $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
            height: 40
        }, function () {
            dialog.data.fadeOut(200, function () {
                dialog.container.fadeOut(200, function () {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $.modal.close();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    },
    validate: function () {
        contact.message = '';
        var fail = false;
        if (!$('#contact-name').val()) {
            contact.message += 'First Name is required. ';
            fail = true;
        }
        //#contact-container 
        if (!$('#contact-lname').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Last Name is required. ';
            fail = true;
        }
        var email = $('#contact-email').val();
        if (!email) {
            contact.message += 'Email is required. ';
            fail = true;
        }
        else {
            if (!contact.validateEmail(email)) {
                contact.message += 'Email is invalid. ';
                fail = true;
            }
        }

        var zip = $('#contact-zip').val();
        if (!zip) {
            contact.message += '2' + zip + '2';
            contact.message += 'ZIP is required. ';
            fail = true;
        }
        else{
            if (!contact.isValidZipCode(zip)) {
                contact.message += 'ZIP is invalid. ';
                fail = true;
            }
        }

        var age = $('#contact-age').val();
        if (!age){
            contact.message += 'Age is required. ';
            fail = true;
        }
        else{
            if (!contact.validateAge(age)) {
                contact.message += 'Age is invalid. ';
                fail = true;
            }
        }

        if (!$('#contact-message').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Message is required.';
            fail = true;
        }

        //if (contact.message.length > 0) {
    //      return true;
        //}
        else {
            if (fail) return false;
            else return true;
        }
    },

    isValidZipCode: function (value) {
    var re = /^\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?$/;
    return (re.test(value));
    },

    validateAge: function (age) {
        if (isNan(age)) return false;
        var a = parseInt(age);
        if (a > 0 && a < 100) return true;
        else return false;
    },

    validateEmail: function (email) {
        var at = email.lastIndexOf("@");

        // Make sure the at (@) sybmol exists and  
        // it is not the first or last character
        if (at < 1 || (at + 1) === email.length)
            return false;

        // Make sure there aren't multiple periods together
        if (/(\.{2,})/.test(email))
            return false;

        // Break up the local and domain portions
        var local = email.substring(0, at);
        var domain = email.substring(at + 1);

        // Check lengths
        if (local.length < 1 || local.length > 64 || domain.length < 4 || domain.length > 255)
            return false;

        // Make sure local and domain don't start with or end with a period
        if (/(^\.|\.$)/.test(local) || /(^\.|\.$)/.test(domain))
            return false;

        // Check for quoted-string addresses
        // Since almost anything is allowed in a quoted-string address,
        // we're just going to let them go through
        if (!/^"(.+)"$/.test(local)) {
            // It's a dot-string address...check for valid characters
            if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%*\/?|^{}`~&'+=_\.]*$/.test(local))
                return false;
        }

        // Make sure domain contains only valid characters and at least one period
        if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/.test(domain) || domain.indexOf(".") === -1)
            return false;   

        return true;
    },
    showError: function () {
        $('#contact-container .contact-message')
            .html($('<div class="contact-error"></div>').append(contact.message))
            .fadeIn(200);
    }
};

contact.init();});
```

This is the PHP file called by the javascript to make the form

```
    $output = "<div style='display:none'>
<div class='contact-top'></div>
<div class='contact-content'>

    <div class='contact-loading' style='display:none'></div>
    <div class='contact-message' style='display:none'></div>
    <form action='#' style='display:none'>
        <label for='contact-name'>First Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' />
        <label for='contact-lname'>Last Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-lname' class='contact-input' name='lname' tabindex='1002' />
        <label for='contact-email'>Email:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1003' />
        <label for='contact-zip'>ZIP:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-zip' class='contact-input' name='zip' tabindex='1004' />
        <label for='contact-age'>Age:</label>
        <input type='text' id='contact-age' class='contact-input' name='age' tabindex='1005' />
```

Comment: Change `if (!$('#contact-container #contact-name').val()) {`
 to `if (!$('#contact-name').val()) {`. Won't fix your problem, but IDs are unique in an HTML file so having them cascaded is a waste of time and effort. And if you have a second `ID="contact-lname"` that that WILL be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this selector `$('#contact-lname')` instead of yours. It seems to me that your `#contact-lname` is not in `#contact-container`, or you have dublicate containers with `id="contact-container"` or `id="contact-lname"` on your page.

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
if ( $.trim($('input[name="name"]').val()) == "") {
        contact.message += 'First Name is required. ';
        fail = true;
    }

if ( $.trim($('input[name="lname"]').val()) == "") {
        contact.message += 'Last Name is required. ';
        fail = true;
    }
```

After updating the question, i assume that you are loading your form element from the `contact.php` file.

```
$.get("data/contact.php", function(data){
```

then you have to validate your contact form into the `contact.php`.

because your jQuery code load once when you refresh your page, and that time all the DOM elements of your page also loaded, your jquery code can't detect your form elements because your are loading that elements from `$.get()` through external file that `contact.php`

Comment: I tried this, but the result is the same. It seems as if the javascript code isn't getting the form elements I added. The original code I'm looking at is above if you have time!

Comment: @Contechtions Please provide the complete code how you tried?

Comment: @Contechtions is the `$output` comes from any ajax request or it in the same page?? cause if you are loading the `contact form` from `contact.php` as i see then you have to validate your form into the `contact.php`

Comment: That was some great insight! I'm just wondering why my Firstname field and Email field verification work while the other fields do not.